# Sorting based on certain value in a string.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, scripting

I have a file with contents like this :

```
    666500872101_002.log
    738500861101_003.log
    738500861101_002.log
    666500872101_001.log
    741500881101_001.log
    738500861101_001.log
    741500881101_002.log
    666500872101_003.log
    741500881101_003.log
    666500872101_004.log
```

I need to Sort the rows based on the values in fields 5 to 8,  i.e.  7415**0088**1101_003.log at first and then based on the part number of log i.e.
741500881101_**003**.log to get something like this :

```
738500861101_001.log
738500861101_002.log
738500861101_003.log
666500872101_001.log
666500872101_002.log
666500872101_003.log
666500872101_004.log        
741500881101_001.log
741500881101_002.log
741500881101_003.log
```

Can't get any good results using `sort` please help.

Comment: What did you try so far? Can we see them if you have any?

Comment: can you try `sort -n -k1.5,1.8 -k1.14,1.16 fileToSort.log` or  `sort -n -k1.5,1.8 -n -k1.14,1.16 fileToSort.log` and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Found this.. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350367/sort-a-file-based-on-the-middle-part

Comment: @Allan thanks man , I was stuck in using only sort -k1,1   didn't know I could even use decimal to sort based on certain fields. Thanks

Comment: Great, then I will just add it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort` command wit the following options:

```
sort -n -k1.5,1.8 -n -k1.14,1.16 fileToSort.log
```

Options:

- `-n` for numerical sorting
- `-k1.5,1.8` and `-k1.14,1.16` to define your sorting keys

**Example:**

```
$ sort -n -k1.5,1.8 -n -k1.14,1.16 fileToSort 
738500861101_001.log
738500861101_002.log
738500861101_003.log
666500872101_001.log
666500872101_002.log
666500872101_003.log
666500872101_004.log
741500881101_001.log
741500881101_002.log
741500881101_003.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as part of learning SPARK. I am not UNIX shell programmer. Hence thought of solving the problem using spark

```
val logList = Array("666500872101_002.log","738500861101_003.log","738500861101_002.log","666500872101_001.log","741500881101_001.log","738500861101_001.log","741500881101_002.log","666500872101_003.log","741500881101_003.log","666500872101_004.log")

val logListRDD = sc.parallelize(logList)
logListRDD.map(x=>((x.substring(4,8), x.slice(x.indexOfSlice("_") +1, x.indexOfSlice("."))),x)).sortByKey().values.collect.take(20)
```

Output:

> Array[String] = Array(738500861101_001.log, 738500861101_002.log, 738500861101_003.log, 666500872101_001.log, 666500872101_002.log, 666500872101_003.log, 666500872101_004.log, 741500881101_001.log, 741500881101_002.log, 741500881101_003.log)

Explaining what I did

*sc.parallelize(logList)* - is the step to create an RDD which is the core component of spark.

*map(x=>((x.substring(4,8), x.slice(x.indexOfSlice("_") +1, x.indexOfSlice("."))),x))* - This extracts the contents from Array and generates a key value pair. In our case, value is the ***.log value and key is an Array of Substrings based on which we wanted to sort (0086, 001). KeyValue pair will look like [(0086, 001),738500861101_001.log]

*sortByKey()* - Sorts the data based on the Key generated above

*values* - gets the value corresponding to the key

*collect.take(20)* -> Displays the o/p on screen